# changing transaction isolation level by configuration

Tags: sql-server

We have somo blocking problems because workflow foundation creates lots of serializable transactions.

Do you know a way for changing every transaction in sql server from serializable to readcommitted?

Can it be made through configuration?

Answer (score 1):

No (AFAIK), you can configure the default isolation level that is used if one is not specified, but not if the isolation level is specified within in the transaction (which overrides the configured default). Even if you could, it would be **dangerous** as the behavior of the transaction may require the specified isolation level to function properly.